# Give an example to show that computing $ \frac{x - y}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}$ is not always more accurate for computing $fl(\sqrt x - \sqrt y)$?

Tags: numerical-methods

I assume that we are working on a machine with rounded four-digit decimal arithmetic, I know that we have this formula:

$\sqrt x - \sqrt y = \frac{x - y}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}$

Since there is cancelation error in machine so it is better to use this formula for computing $fl(\sqrt x - \sqrt y)$ .But can you give me an example that computing simple difference for computing $fl(\sqrt x - \sqrt y)$ (I mean directly compute $\sqrt x - \sqrt y$) is more accurate than computing $\frac{x - y}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}$ ?

I tried lots of examples but using formula is always more accurate or both of them have the same accuracy ,can any one help me?

Comment: What do you mean by $fl$?

Comment: $fl(x)$ is floating-point version of x.

Comment: $fl(x) = x(1+\delta ) s.t |\delta | < epsilon machine$

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the formula is mainly when $x$ and $y$ are close together.  When they are not, the direct method has a fair chance of being better.
For example, with $x = 6$ and $y = 1$, the direct method gives
$\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} = 2.449 - 1.000 = 1.449$, while the formula gives
$$\frac{x - y}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}} = \frac{6 - 1}{2.449 + 1.000} = \frac{5}{3.449} = 1.450$$
and it happens that $\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{1} = 1.4494897\ldots$ is closer to $1.449$ than to $1.450$.